# Loading JSON into Mongodb using Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Edit- This actually works great...if you actually call the function at the end..

I'm converting an xml file into JSON as follows:

```
const convert = require('xml-js');
const rawXml = require('./data');

const dataToJson = convert.xml2json(rawXml, {compact: true, spaces: 4});

console.log('xml to JSON worked');

module.exports = dataToJson;
```

And then want to load this into my Data model in MongoDB using mongoose.

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: __dirname + '/../variables.env' });


const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;


const dataToJson = require('../convert-data');
const Data = require('../models/data_model');


console.log(dataToJson);

async function loadData() {
try {
    await Data.insertMany(dataToJson);
    console.log('It Worked!');
    process.exit();
}catch(e){
    console.log('Oops...')
    console.error(e);
    process.exit();
 }
};

loadData();
```

The JSON shows up fine on the console, but does nothing when it gets to the loadData() function, not even throwing an error. Using MongoDb compass shows that nothing has been inserted into the DB.

Comment: you are not calling the loadData function.

Comment: @RahulSharma post you comment as answer so the OP can accept it :) So other ppl know it's over

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT He updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not calling the loadData function.

```
async function loadData() {
try {
    await Data.insertMany(dataToJson);
    console.log('It Worked!');
    process.exit();
}catch(e){
    console.log('Oops...')
    console.error(e);
    process.exit();
 }
};

loadData();
```